# iOS OTA distribution UIWebView crash

Tags: ios, ota

There are particular web pages that when loaded into a UIWebView, crash - but only when using the app downloaded via OTA enterprise distribution. The crash occurs after web page has finished loading at the webViewDidFinishLoad method.

If I do the exact same action on the app when directly installed through XCode or TestFlight, the crash doesn't occur.

This behaviour is very consistent - I can't workout why the crash only happens on an app downloaded through OTA. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

An example of the web page that causes the crash is:
https://www.google.com.au/url?q=http://www.xperiencerealty.com.au/super-agents/jeremy-paikaew-guardian-agent-property-manager/&sa=U&ei=MPa1VP-GF8PAmQXd74LIBg&ved=0CBQQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHeeCc71Z7M5zYMVoRr1yy7GPTKjQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to make sure that this was answered!

Re-creating my certificate in the Apple developer portal sorted out this issue. For some reason it seems that certificates created before the release of iOS8 cause this crash.